# iterate loop from php associative array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have this **`PHP array storing code`**(the data of array is came from database query) then the array will be pass to **`JQuery`**. My problem is I'm getting **`Undefined value`** when I retrieve the data from php Array. I use **`$.Each`** loop in `JQuery`. My question is, how to iterate loop of php `associative array` using `JQuery`?

Here's my code so far:

[CONSOLE.LOG/NETWORK IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/ze2e3099f/full/)

**PHP Array storing**

```
                                 **** loop here*****

$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']][$rowInnerJoin['DateField']] = 
                            array('DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']);

echo json_encode($ListOfWorkOrderDates);
```

**Jquery Loop**

```
/// Here where I get confuse. How can I retrieve those data from php using jquery loop

$.ajax({
          url:'getWorkOrders.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:{id:_WOID},
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(output){

             console.log(output);

             $.each(output, function(index, object){

                   counter++;


                   ListOfPercentage.push(object.DateField);
                   ListOfDates.push(object.DatePosted);
             });    
          }
});
```

Comment: inspect the response using the browser network tabs(developer tools) to see the actual response format... and post it along with the question

Comment: This is a primary function of XML and JSON formatting, have you looked into these yet?

Comment: how are you sending array? is it json_encoded ? What does data sample look like?

Comment: @charlietfl yes.. it is `json_encoded`

Comment: @ArunPJohny ok wait.

Comment: One character difference and you will run into problems, `o`, `O`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I already update my post.

Comment: there are no properties like `WorkOrder` or `DateField` in the returned value...

Comment: ok.. I already removed `ListOfSequence.push(object.WorkOrder);`, but still I get the `undefined value`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ListOfWorkOrderDates[$rowInnerJoin['WorkOrder']][$rowInnerJoin['DateField']] = 
                            array('DatePosted' => $rowInnerJoin['DatePosted']);
```

Did you check your exact json response using firebug or chrome dev tools.

I believe object.WorkOrder might return undefined, because your json does'nt seem to have a WorkOrder key?

for the js to work, your json response should be something like

```
[
    {
        "WorkOrder": "w1",
        "DateField": "D1",
        "DatePosted": "DP1"
    },
    {
        "WorkOrder": "w2",
        "DateField": "D3",
        "DatePosted": "DP2"
    }
]
```

a quick code i used to generate the above response

```
$response=array();
    $response[0]=array("WorkOrder"=>"w1","DateField"=>"D1","DatePosted"=>"DP1");
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: how can I do that in PHP Array that kind of arrangement?